# Hibernate Validation - Require validation on specific endpoints

Tags: hibernate, validation

I am trying to figure out how to apply certain field validation rules when particular endpoints are called.

I have an `invite` entity that has a `List<applicant>` which is a second entity. This creates one table for invite and another table for applicant in a OneToMany relationship (meaning you can have one invite that has many applicants).

The invite gets submitted with the "moveindate" on the invite and the nested applicant has "firstname", "lastname" and "email" on the applicant.

The applicants will then individually provide additional detail (i.e. ssn) through a second endpoint.

The problem is that when the invite is submitted it will not have all the required fields (`@NotNull`) for the applicant populated (i.e. SSN). This only gets added and required when the applicant follows up and submits the application.

How can I allow the applicant to be created when the invite is submitted, but only require `@NotNull` when the applicant follows-up and submits their application on the second end-point?

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class invitecontroller {

    @PostMapping("/v1/invite")
    public void invite(@Valid @RequestBody invite invite){
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
public class invite {
    
    @Id private Long inviteid;

    @NotNull private Date moveindate;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inviteid")
    private List<applicant> applicants;

}
```

```
@Entity
public class applicant {

    @Id private Long applicantid;

    @NotNull private Long inviteid;

    @NotBlank private String firstname;
    @NotBlank private String lastname;
    @NotBlank private String email;

    @NotNull private String ssn;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use validation groups:

```
public interface Invitation extends javax.validation.groups.Default {}

public interface Submission extends javax.validation.groups.Default {}


@RestController
@Validated
public class InviteController {

    @PostMapping("/v1/invite")
    public void invite(@Validated(Invitation.class) @RequestBody Invite invite){
    }


    @PostMapping("/v1/submit")
    public void submit(@Validated(Submission.class) @RequestBody Invite invite){
    }
}

@Entity
public class applicant {

    @Id private Long applicantid;

    @NotNull private Long inviteid;

    @NotBlank(groups = Invitation.class) private String firstname; // only required for invitation
    @NotBlank(groups = Submission.class) private String lastname; //only required for submission
    @NotBlank private String email; // required for both, since it remains in the default group

    @NotNull private String ssn;

}
```

Comment: Bingo, looks like that worked. I haven't tried the second endpoint, but doing negative testing on the first endpoint leads me to believe that this works. Thanks alot.